# Calling two versions of the same template function passed as an argument in C++

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++14, template-argument-deduction

I want to call two versions of the same function, in a function. For example:

```cpp
template<class F>
auto ulp_error(F f, float x)
{
    float f1 = f(x);
    double x2 = x;
    float f2 = static_cast<float>(f(x2));
    return boost::math::float_distance(f1, f2);
}
```

Now I'd like to call this function via:

```cpp
ulp_error(std::log, 1.2f);
```

but I get the following error on clang-1000.11.45.5:

```sh
fatal error: no matching function for call to 'ulp_error'
    ulp_error(std::log, 1.2f);
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'F'
```

Ok, how about this?

```cpp
ulp_error<decltype(std::log)>(std::log, 1.2f);
```

which gives the following error:

```sh
fatal error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?
    ulp_error<decltype(std::log)>(std::log, 1.2f);
```

How can I pass (say) `std::log` as an argument to a function and call it with two different types?

Comment: The problem is it's not clear to the compiler `which` [log](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) function you want. The could all be a match for `f`.

Comment: I call `log(float)` and `log(double)` in the function body.

Comment: If you are attempting to capture a *family* of functions then templates are not the solution. The template argument will need to be evaluated to a specific function type for each instantiation of `ulp_error` and each call needs to refer to a specific overload. It can't be both functions in the same instantiation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Do you have a suggestion for a solution?

Comment: The answer bellow looks like the only easy way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe as follows?

```
ulp_error([](auto x){ return std::log(x); }, 1.2f);
```

I mean... `std::log` is a overloaded function; so using simply `std::log` (or `decltype(std::log)` doesn't works because the compiler can't choose the correct version. And you can't pass both of they.

But passing it inside a generic-template, the corrected version is selected by the type of the `x` lambda parameter.

Another possible solution should be casting to the correct type, by example

```
ulp_error(static_cast<double(*)(double)>(&std::log), 1.2f);
```

but (MHO) I find this syntax a little ugly.

Comment: I was not aware that generic lambdas could be passed as callable objects. I assumed it was equivalent to a templated functions but this actually introduces a lot of new possibilities.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - yes: it's very useful; unfortunately require C++14 (no generic lambda in C++11) but its possible to simulate this with a simple struct with a template function in it.

Comment: @user14717 - sorry: there was a wrong closed parentheses; corrected (I hope).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux lambdas are not functions, but objects (closures), so yes, they can be passed as an argument to a template actually, the same way as non-generic lambdas could be passed.

Comment: @SergeyA I had a mental model that generic lambdas worked essential as templates for callable objects but it now seems like a ridiculous idea.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, yeah, they work like a template member of non-template class.